# How to build poppler on Windows and include Poppler in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt5, poppler, poppler-utils

I am trying to use Poppler with Qt 5.6, using these steps:

- I downloaded `poppler-23.12.0.tar.xz` and `poppler-data-0.4.12.tar.gz` on the website: https://poppler.freedesktop.org/
- I unpacked them and added:

  ```
  set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH};C:\\Users\\ntronghoa\\Music\\poppler-23.12.0\\poppler")
  set(Poppler_DIR "C:\\Users\\ntronghoa\\Music\\poppler\\poppler-23.11.0\\Library\\lib\\pkgconfig")

  find_package(Poppler REQUIRED) to CMakeList on Qt Creator
  ```

But I get this error:

> C:\Users\ntronghoa\Documents\ERGFFF\CMakeLists.txt:14: error: By not providing "FindPoppler.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
> asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Poppler", but
> CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Poppler" with any
> of the following names:
>
> PopplerConfig.cmake
> poppler-config.cmake
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Poppler" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
> "Poppler_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
> "Poppler" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
> been installed.

How can I build Poppler, include, and use it with Qt in Qt Creator?